# Using print() from static function in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I need to use print() within a static function in Swift. The function needs to be called using an observer pattern as seen below:

```
import Foundation

@NSApplicationMain
class Application: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    static var commandArgsObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override init() {
        Application.setObserver()
        ...
    }
    
    static func setObserver()
        commandArgsObserver = storedSettings.observe(\.commandArgs, options: [.initial, .new], changeHandler: { (defaults, change) in
            if let newArgs = change.newValue {
                if newArgs != nil {
                    handleNewCommandLineArguments(arguments: newArgs!)
                    ...
                }
            }
        })
    }

    static func handleNewCommandLineArguments(arguments: [String]) {
        print("I do not see this... :(")
        ...
    }
}
```

I can confirm that print() works from init(). Code immediately following print() is also being executed. I'm thinking the print function doesn't properly get the "right" standard output?

For additional context, this GUI application starts as a launch agent and runs continuously in the system menu. What I'm trying to do now is print text when a second instance of the app is run via Terminal line with the -help parameter.

Thanks for any help with this! I'm not particularly familiar with macOS/Swift and have more experience with Windows/C#

Comment: Have you confirmed that `newArgs` actually has a value and is not nil and that the `handleNewCommandLineArguments(arguments: newArgs!)` line is being executed?

Comment: Yes, code after the print function is executed. I wrote to a file to check this. Using XCode 12.0.1 but tested it by having the app launched as a launch agent and then running another instance of the app from Terminal (zsh).

Comment: Cmd-click on `print`, and make sure you're calling the function you think you're calling. If anyone has created a static `print` function on this type, then this is the behavior you'd expect. The other likely cause is that somewhere in your app you've closed stdout, which would also have this symptom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and feel a little dumb. The second instance of the app was just passing command line parameters to the first instance (using the observer) and quitting. The print function was being run by the first instance (not the one running in Terminal).

To fix this, I have to print text before the second instance of the app quits so that stdout is pointed to Terminal (duh).

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function only logs to the debugger, you need to use either `NSLog` or `OSLog`

NSLog:

```
let str = "Some string"
NSLog("\(str)") 
// or
NSLog("%@", str)
```

OSLog:

```
import os.log

let str = "Some string"
os_log("%@", str)
```

Comment: This writes a message to the Console (and it works where the print function is now). I'm trying to print text as command line output to Terminal though.